# Bootstrap tour n.data(...).tip is not a function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tour

I am trying to integrate the bootstraptour on my website.

I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: n.data(...).tip is not a function

I load my resources like this:

```
<link href="<?=base_url()?>assets/css/bootstrap-tour.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer="defer" src="<?=base_url()?>assets/js/bootstrap-tour.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and in  my view I perform this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Instance the tour
        var tour = new Tour({
            steps: [
                {
                    element: "#adminvolunteers",
                    title: "Title of my step",
                    content: "Content of my step"
                },
                {
                    element: "#adminorganizations",
                    title: "Title of my step",
                    content: "Content of my step"
                }
            ]});

        // Initialize the tour
        tour.init();

        // Start the tour
        tour.start();
    });
</script>
```

If i remove the defer in the script load I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: n.popover is not a function

Answer (score 3):

I've solved the same problem using the **standalone** version.
So i've downloaded the last release from github at [GitHub Repository of Bootstrap-tour](https://github.com/sorich87/bootstrap-tour/releases) and i added the content in my web page with the following order:

1. `boostrap.min.css` (i use the 4.1.0 version)
2. `boostrap-tour-standalone.min.css`
3. JQuery (version 3.2.1)
4. `bootstrap.min.js` (version 4.1.0)
5. `bootstrap-tour-standalone.min.js`

and it's ok.

Comment: worked for me with bootstrap 4.1.3 with bootstrap-tour-standalone-* and bootstrap.bundle.min.js

Comment: Is this working with bootstrap 5? I tried but getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

**I've moved to [Bootstrap Tourist](https://github.com/IGreatlyDislikeJavascript/bootstrap-tourist)** since the standalone version as suggested in the other answer is causing some design issues with bootstrap (latest version).

Bootstrap Tourist is much similar to Bootstrap Tour and gives much more customization.